# Is it possible to lock down the http / https proxy settings on an Android phone?

Tags: tls, android, proxy, http-proxy, squid

Is there any way to lock down the [proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069032/18149) on an Android Phone so that they can't be changed by anyone but the person with the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Device Management (MDM) solutions exist that allow you to control and lock down settings on the device, as well as manage devices from a central location.